# Write to mongo db from other program?

Tags: meteor

I'm new with meteor and mongo so maybe my question will be stupid.

How can I update meteor mongo database from another program?

For example, I want to have bash script that adds one document to collection when it is executed.

If that was SQL like sqlite, I would simply have script like this one:

```
#/bin/bash

sqlite mydatabase.sql "INSERT ...."
```

Comment: Is it important that it be an external script? I ask because it's actually a lot easier to get meteor to initialize its own database.

Comment: @DavidWeldon - Well, my idea is to write data from external program. My meteor app would be some kind of monitor app, like reading nice and organized logs.

Comment: This is pretty easy. you can modify your database from anywhere outside meteor and your meteor applications will pick up the changes(reactive).

Comment: @MurWade is right, make sure you connect to your MongoDb port (default for Meteor is 3001)

Comment: Answer in comment(s) detected